# How to select a row having a column with max value with a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table with the next columns

```
MSG_ID          NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
CREATION_DATE            DATE           
PORT                     VARCHAR2(50)   
MESSAGE                  VARCHAR2(1024) 
IP_ADDRESS               VARCHAR2(50)   
PARSED                   NUMBER(1)      
PARSED_ON                DATE
```

Where parse time is parsed_on -  creation_date.

I would like to know if it is possible in 1 single query extract for each hour the message that take longer to parse, getting the HOUR, PORT, MSG_ID MINUTES...I am blocked here

```
select TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') || ':mm' HOUR, PORT, MSG_ID, ROUND(MAX(parsed_on -  creation_date)) * 24*60 MINUTES
        from T_INCOME_CALLS 
         where TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy') 
        group by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24'), PORT, MSG_ID
         order by TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function row_number to find row with largest parse time in each hour like this:

```
select *
from (
    select to_number(to_char(creation_date, 'HH24')) as hour,
        port,
        msg_id,
        round(parsed_on - creation_date) * 24 * 60 as parse_time,
        row_number() over (
            partition by to_char(creation_date, 'HH24'), port, msg_id
            order by (parsed_on - creation_date) desc nulls last
            ) as rn
    from t_income_calls t
    where creation_date between trunc(sysdate) 
                            and trunc(sysdate + 1) - interval '1' second
    ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Also, notice the filter. I used date range instead of to_char on creation_date. The use of to_char on creation_date inhibits the use of index on creation_date if it is present.

Comment: I got a ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected at Line: 7 Column: 9

Comment: @enLopes - Missed a comma. Updated. Try now

Comment: The OP's `GROUP BY` clause includes `TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24'), PORT, MSG_ID` - the `PARTITION BY` clause should do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that the need is for the item that takes most time, per hour, for a grouping of IP_ADDRESS and PORT, which is different to your original query. I am also assuming MSG_ID is unique.

If you want 1 and only 1 row per recorded hour then use `row_number()`, if however you want tied values as well substitute `dense_rank()` in the query below. The create_on date has been used as a tie-beaker for sorting.

```
SELECT
       TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') || ':mm' HOUR
     , PORT, MSG_ID
     , ROUND(parsed_on -  creation_date) * 24*60 MINUTES
FROM (
      SELECT
            T_INCOME_CALLS.*
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IP_ADDRESS, port, TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') 
                                ORDER BY (parsed_on - creation_date) desc, CREATION_DATE) AS rn
      FROM T_INCOME_CALLS
      WHERE CREATION_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND CREATION_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
      ) 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Please avoid converting dates into strings for your where clause, this is not efficient . Instead leave created_on untouched and amend the criteria to suit that data which will allow access to indexes for the filtering.

Comment: I got ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected at Line: 8 Column: 12    :-(

Comment: sorry there was a copy/paste remnant on a line. the from clause should be clean now.

Comment: `SELECT *, another_column` is invalid syntax - you need to use a table name/alias `SELECT Table_name.*, another_column`. You also have a syntax error (trailing comma) in the `FROM` clause and a random additional `port` table that is `CROSS JOIN`ed. You are also partitioning by `IP_ADDRESS` when it should be `MSG_ID`.

Comment: that comma in the from clause was an error, no cross join intended (and it was a column name as well *grrr*); thanks for the reminder on *

Comment: @MT0 the partition by ip_address was deliberate, grouping by an already unique column isn't going to achieve much of anything useful, my "guess" is that ip+port is more useful, added note to this effect.

Comment: Then you need to explain why you have made that change in your answer as it is not obvious (and it makes assumptions about the data as the OP has not stated in the question that `MSG_ID` is unique).

Comment: @MT0 yes, noted, and already done. If my assumptions are wrong then the partitioning may be set back to `msg_id, port` instead of 'i_address,port`

Answer (score 1):

You can get it also without a sub-query when you use [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) function:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24') || ':mm' HOUR, PORT, MSG_ID, 
    MAX(MESSAGE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY (parsed_on - creation_date) desc, CREATION_DATE)                
FROM T_INCOME_CALLS 
WHERE CREATION_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND CREATION_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24'), PORT, MSG_ID
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24');
```

Comment: I got a ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis at Line: 2 Column: 105 :-(

Comment: Remove the `OVER( .. )` part of the statement (which is syntactically invalid as it is missing the [`PARTITION BY` keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF51190)) - it should not be include when used as an aggregate function. The partitioning is already handled by the `GROUP BY` clause.